# How to build a Python REPL with non-blocking matplotlib (like IPython's %matplotlib) on macOS

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, plot, ipython

I am writing a terminal REPL in macOS, and having a hard time replicating the non-blocking matplotlib plotting behavior that you get with IPython's `%matplotlib` magic.

Consider the following simple REPL (I am using Python 3.5 from Anaconda on macOS 10.12):

```
#!/usr/bin/env pythonw

# Basic REPL (note: doesn't show output)

_globals = _locals = globals().copy()

while True:
    command = input(">>> ")
    res = exec(command, _globals, _locals)
```

The `pythonw` is necessary to get the plot to focus correctly.

If you run in this shell

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1, 2])
plt.show()
```

it will block.  I've tried

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.interactive(True)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1, 2])
```

This doesn't block, but the plot window that appears is completely unresponsive. I can't even close it. Running

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1, 2])
plt.show(block=False)
```

is the same.

On the other hand, if you run

```
%matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1, 2])
```

in IPython 5.1.0, it works perfectly. The REPL doesn't block, and I can interact with the plot.

I've tried reading the IPython source to figure out what I need to replicate, but I can't figure it out. I've even tried running `IPython.core.pylabtools.activate_matplotlib("MacOSX")`, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered that IPython 4.2.1 actually does this wrong, which allowed me to bisect the IPython codebase and find the answer.

IPython 5, which uses prompt-toolkit, has a special inputhook that it passes to prompt-toolkit's `eventloop` argument of `run_application`. IPython's inputhook is defined in [IPython.terminal.pt_inputhooks.osx](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/terminal/pt_inputhooks/osx.py). The code does a bunch of `ctypes` calls into the macOS APIs (basically, to get the GUI eventloop).

I don't know how to use this for the dummy REPL from my question, but I am actually using prompt-toolkit, so this is fine for me. To use it, use

```
from IPython.terminal.pt_inputhooks.osx import inputhook
from prompt_toolkit.shortcuts import create_eventloop

# <prompt-toolkit stuff>
... 
run_application(eventloop=create_eventloop(inputhook)
```

You also still do need the `matplotlib.interactive(True)` call before importing `matplotlib.pyplot` to make the plots show automatically (otherwise you have to call `plt.show()` all the time, and, more importantly, the plots will block).